# how to get group videos list using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i use the Group Videos API(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/videos) want to get video list, i had selected all permissions,but get empty array, as pic:

[image]

but use /v2.4/{group-id}/feed ,i can get all post(contian video):

[image]

permissions:

[image]

is /v2.4/{group-id}/videos API has bug? or i use the wrong way?

if you know please help me ,thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found this is a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1447158552191092/